# MySql Duplicate-data an entry on another table

Tags: mysql, duplicate-data

I have table1,table2 => all fields are identical except that table2 two has an extra field which is a FK of table1

```
**table1** *ID*,content,status
**table2** *ID*,content,status,tid
```

so tid = table1 id.

I need to copy a row from table1 one to table2 so esentially the table2 would be a backup of table1. I can do it using mysql,then php, then mysql again I was wondering if you could have a simpler solution on mysql :)

hope its not too complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy every row in `table1` into `table2`, you could do:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, content, status, tid)
  SELECT id, content, status, id FROM b;
```

If `table2` isn't empty, you could add an `ON DUPLICATE KEY...` clause to deal with clashes.

EDIT

If you just want to copy one row, you can add a `WHERE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, content, status, tid) 
  SELECT id, content, status, id FROM b WHERE id=123;
```

Comment: no its a single entry/record I need to copy, therefore I can have multiple versions of that record and still keep table1 clean if that makes sense

Comment: ok, check out my edit. Is `id` the same in both tables, or e.g. `auto_increment`?

Comment: this sounds abit more promissing :) the edit part :) I will give it a go and get back to u :)

Comment: well both id on table1 and table2 are autoinc... but tid is the same as `WHERE id=123` id

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (content, status, tid) SELECT content, status, ID FROM table1
```